# Cannot get text from text area

Tags: dart

I cannot get text from my textarea :

Very simple textarea :

```dart
<textarea id="message" placeholder="Type your text here..."></textarea>
```

My dart code :

```dart
var area = document.query('#message');
document.query("#send").on.click.add((e) { 
   print('send ${area.text}');
});
```

When i write a message in area and press send , just display :

```
send
```

I don't understand why my message is not print. 'text' is not the correct field ? (same problem with innerHtml)
When I add

```dart
area.text = 'Hello';
```

The message is visible in textarea and print is well.

Comment: I've never used Dart, but try `area.value` instead. It sounds like `text` just gets the children of the *node* as text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `area.value` instead of `area.text`. `area.value` is a property of `TextAreaElement` that gets the actual value displayed, whereas `area.text` is a property of `Node` that gets or sets the content of `area` as a text node.

Comment: My problem was Dart Editor put a warning on the area.value.
But if I declare the area as TextAreaElement works fine :

TextAreaElement area = document.query('#message');